# How can I set the column properties(DisplayFormatString to be precise) of a aspx(devExpress) grid from code behind?

Tags: asp.net, devexpress, aspxgridview

I have an aspx(devexpress) grid. Using which I generate columns dynamically from code behind.Below is the code from my grid_databinding event.

```
GridViewDataTextColumn bfield = new GridViewDataTextColumn();
if (TestString.YearSelectedNames.ToString().Length > 4)
{  string colName = string.Empty;
if (iCount % 2 == 0)
  {

   colName = TestString.YearSelectedNames.ToString().Substring(5, 4) + "-" + dtFreezing.Columns[iCount].ColumnName.ToString();
   bfield.HeaderTemplate = new DevxGridViewTemplate(ListItemType.Header, typeof(Label), colName, iCount);
  }
  else
     {
     colName = TestString.YearSelectedNames.ToString().Substring(0, 4) + "-" + dtFreezing.Columns[iCount].ColumnName.ToString().Replace('1', ' ');
     bfield.HeaderTemplate = new DevxGridViewTemplate(ListItemType.Header, typeof(Label), colName, iCount);
     }

}
else
    {
    bfield.HeaderTemplate = new DevxGridViewTemplate(ListItemType.Header, typeof(Label), dtFreezing.Columns[iCount].ColumnName.Trim(), iCount);
    }
    bfield.HeaderStyle.HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Center;
    bfield.HeaderStyle.Wrap = DevExpress.Utils.DefaultBoolean.True;
    bfield.Name = dtFreezing.Columns[iCount].ColumnName.Trim();
    bfield.Width = Unit.Pixel(120);
    bfield.VisibleIndex = iCount;
    bfield.DataItemTemplate = new DevxGridViewTemplate(ListItemType.Item, typeof(Label), dtFreezing.Columns[iCount].ColumnName.Trim(), iCount);
    bfield.CellStyle.HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Right;
    bfield.PropertiesTextEdit.DisplayFormatString = "N2";
    gridViewProductCrop.Columns.Add(bfield);
```

Here the line of code

```
bfield.PropertiesTextEdit.DisplayFormatString = "N2";
```

is where I am trying to set the property of the grids' column to display only two decimals after the decimal point.

This line of code doesn't seem to work in the first place.

I have even tried using `"{0:0.00}"` and `"{0:N2}"` but in vain

Possible reason being that I am writing this line of code in the grid's databinding event. But how else can I set the column properties from code behind

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to change this code

```
bfield.PropertiesTextEdit.DisplayFormatString = "N2";
```

to

```
this.PropertiesTextEdit.DisplayFormatString = "N2";
```

i think this happen coz u loop the object(make a new object) and the properties would be overwrite.

CMIIW

Comment: So in that case on every iteration of the for loop it should be a different object assigned to bfield. Setting the property for every different object should not be overridden if that is what you are trying to say.

Comment: Yeah, the object should not be overridden. Sorry but what i means it would use last object's settings property(but im wrong coz u put the object to List/Columns, sorry hehehe).

But after i look at ur code again, i think the problem is set property after u put the object in List Column.. So try to put the code before add the object to Column...

If it is still not working, im sry for my poor solution and my english ^^.